# SQL Server numeric field primary key field and hibernate "native" generator

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I'm currently studying an existing java application of a client. It use hibernate and SQL Server.

Most of the database table using numeric (20,0) as primary key colume

```
CREATE TABLE [myschema].[WAREHOUSE](
     [ID] [numeric](20, 0) NOT NULL,
```

In hibernate mapping xml

```
<class
    name="com.client.model.Warehouse"
    dynamic-update="true"
    table="WAREHOUSE"
    proxy="com.client.model.Warehouse"
    >

    <id
        name="id"
        type="java.lang.Long"
        column="ID"
        >
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
```

When I tried to add a new warehouse from testing environment, hibernate tried to insert a new record without specifying the ID field. Thus SQL Server throwing exception because ID field cannot be null.

How is this possible? The application is, however, running in production...

Comment: is the setup/database and database settings everything same in prod and dev.

Comment: Ankur I'm double checking on this. Just wondering if the setup above technically possible...

Comment: Assuming your Production app is definitely not inserting the value, You can auto add a primary key with a trigger or sequence in the database. Perform a database compare. I also suggest you use SQL Profiler to confirm your production app is not inserting it explicitly